# Windows Phone 8 SQL lite support PhoneGap 3.1

Tags: sqlite, cordova, windows-phone-8, cordova-3, windows-phone-8-emulator

Is there any other SQL Lite plugin available over Cordova/ PhoneGap 3.1 for Windows Phone 8 except the one mentioned below. Currently we are using below githup project but it giving us issues to handle nested queries Callbacks..
If anyone used this successfully to developed App please let me know So that i can share problem what am facing while using this.. Is there any documentation available other than looking into c sharp code...

https://github.com/lite4cordova/Cordova-SQLitePlugin

Answer (score 0):

Finally i find issue in mine implementation code. The git repo which mentioned above is working fine until now just throw some assertion exception. The issues i was facing was due to multiple Database Connection simultaneously anyway i fixed it by making sure that in application there should be only one Database connection available all time.

Specially be careful while opening or closing database connections